# Forcing a download using <filesMatch> in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to force the download of all files of one folder.

The link on the page looks like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/uploads/documents/file.pdf">Click to download</a>
```

And I have this snippet in my .htaccess

```
<filesMatch ".*uploads/documents.*">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</filesMatch>
```

I already know that the 2 lines inside the tag works, because it works when I put a .htaccess directly inside the folder where I want to force the download with the following code:

```
<Files *.*>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

There seems to be something which I don't understand about the filesMatch tag.

Comment: ftp root? you mean http? htaccess does NOTHING for ftp.You've also misspelled "aplication" (note the 2nd i)

Comment: Please don't use `application/octet-stream` to force a download. It's an abuse of all that is good and true about HTTP.

Comment: What would be a better way to force the download of a document instead of displaying it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please look at the documentation for [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) and [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files), respectively. It clearly states

> The directives given within this section will be applied to any object
>   with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified
>   filename.

That means that in your example it matches against `file.pdf`. Your second example `*.*` matches `file.pdf`, however your first example `.*uploads/documents.*` does not. It actually can never match, since it contains a slash, which is used as a directory separator.

## If you can edit the apache config

You should enclose either `<Files *.*>` or `<Files *.pdf>` (depending on what you want to enforce downloading) in a `Location` directive:

```
<Location "/uploads/documents/">
    <Files *.*>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>
</Location>
```

## If you cannot edit the apache config

Unfortunately, the Location directive is not allowed inside .htaccess files. Just create a .htaccess inside your `/uploads/documents/` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I had looked at the documentation, but it seemed like chinese to me. There really is no way to target a folder through the htaccess folder?

Comment: I ended using PHP to set the correct headers to force the download because I couldn't afford to put an .htaccess in the folder, but I finally understand how the <Files> tag works in an htaccess

Comment: I get the error - <Files> cannot occur within <Location> section - don't think works any more.

Comment: While you force to affect all files the `<Files>` directive isn't necessary. `ForceType` and `Header` are enough. But I'd prefer the `<Files>` directive either while it's semantically more readable.

Answer (score 32):

Searching more info found this code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mov|mp3|jpg|pdf|mp4|avi|wmv)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Worked for me.

Comment: For anyone not sure where to add this snippet. I added this code in a file named `.httaccess` in the same directory as the files want to be downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

This code is perfect if you don't use  `-`  in the file name!

For example, for name-1.mp3, change to name1.mp3

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mp3|avi)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

Clear your browser and check it.