# Download Text file using HTML button with Save as Option

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to download Text File using HTML BUtton using below option :

onclick="window.location.href='../TEST/test.txt'; "

Issue is FIle is getting open in Internat Explorer itself... Firefox is providing Save as option for the file....

Also when I am chaning files extension from .txt to .log file gets open in Notepad throgh Internet Explorer....

Is there any solution from which I will get Save "File Download" Dialog Box for .txt file in Internet Explorer and Firefox?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root

Comment: Thanks Anand for providing reference link... 

I am using Embedded Web Server.

Is there any solution for that?