# Saving .json file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to save json file to my application's directory using javascript. how to do it? my code  only opens a new tab when you click download button and display the content of my json file. I am allowed to use client-side scripting only. I've tried this code but not working.

NOT WORKING CODE:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

var s = fso.CreateTextFile("location", true);

s.WriteLine(json);

s.Close();
```

Here's my code..

HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="survey.manifest">
<head>
    <title>Offline Survey Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/survey.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/survey.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code

```
window.onload=function myFunction()
{
    var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'dButton');
    btn.setAttribute('value', 'download');
    var t=document.createTextNode("DOWNLOAD");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    btn.onclick=function clickedFunction(){
        var url = "http://localhost/JSONFiles/survey.json";
        window.open(url, 'download');
        }
};
```

thanks in advance friends! :)

Comment: Where / how is your page running? This is usually impossible.

Comment: What browser are you running this script in?

Comment: trust me. its running., upon clicking the DOWNLOAD button it opens a new tab in the browser then shows the content of my json file. but i dont want to display it i want to save it.. help please! tnx

Comment: running it on chrome..

Comment: um...ActiveX is a proprietary Microsoft technology. It will only work in IE, and nowadays only if you lessen the security restrictions, as it is a huge security risk.You can trigger the normal download dialog, though, if you set a the right mime/content type

Comment: ow..thanks again for the info..appreciate it..can you give me some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do would kill a lot of kittens.

For safety reasons, a web page cannot use activeX objects on a whim, nor access the local computer resources like file system in any way except what is allowed by standard (basically the cookies and local storage files).

That would allow any Russian hacker and his rabid dog to wreak havoc on computers all over the planet.

You can, however, try to use local storage if your json files are not too bulky and you don't expect to reuse them from another application.

If you plan on downloading json files, just point to them (i.e. put a link to whatever .json file somewhere on your page) and when the user clicks on such a link the browser will pop a save requester to let the user free to save the files in a location of his/her choosing.

Comment: thank you for the info. is there any other solution to save it then? appreciate your help.

Comment: thanks again. but how to do the local storage thingy? how to save it without popping dialogs? i want to save it to my application's directory AUTOMATICALLY. im sorry im just a beginner whose trying to learn from you guys. bear with me.. thanks!!!

Comment: Basically, you can't create files on the local file system without the user giving his/her full consent (by validating a file dialog). This is what security is all about. Local storage allows you to associate some data with a given web site, a bit like cookies, but still these data cannot be accessed outside the browser and are subject to size limits (here again to avoid web pages filling your local disks without the user being aware of it).

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is get a file on your server to download automatically instead of be viewed in the browser, you just need to set the Content-Disposition header the file is sent to the client with to "attachment". The easiest way to do that is to modify the config files for whatever server your using to add a rule for files of type `.json`. The exact methodology will differ depending on your server, though.

Comment: This will still not allow to save the files automatically on the client side, or did I miss something?

Comment: hi. im using wampserver. i tried to save my .json file in the "wampserver/www/JSONFiles/". i want to download that json file and save it to my application's directory. I really dont know the code. help please! thanks guys!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root

Comment: I've got my solution.

window.onload=function myFunction()
{
    var btn=document.createElement('a');
    btn.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost/JSONFiles/survey.json');
    btn.setAttribute('download', 'survey.json');
    var t=document.createTextNode("DOWNLOAD");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
};
the download is working..now my problem is, the file was saved on the "Downloads" folder..any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: That you can't control. If the browser prompts the user for a download location, they can store it wherever they like, but some browsers like Chrome just automatically dump it to the Downloads folder.