# How can I download a MP4 file instead of playing it on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a .mp4 file that I need to download to my system when I click on the anchor tag.

HTML:

```
<a href="DSCSA_webinar.mp4">Download Here</a>
```

Is there any way to download this instead of opening it in a browser?

I needed this to run on IE as well and the only option I have is through javascript or jQuery. Anything else that is simpler can also be suggested.

I am aware of the HTML5 `download` attribute, but it doesn't support on IE.

Answer (score 3):

I found this: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?244007-RESOLVED-Force-download-of-MP3-file-instead-of-streaming and I do similar things with Excel files.

Directly from there:

use a small PHP file to handle the download, put in the same folder as the .mp3:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

which can be accessed in any anchor like this:

```
<a href="direct_download.php?file=fineline.mp3">Download the mp3</a>
```

Comment: This is OK but it assumes they are using a PHP server.

Comment: True. Or at least has it on there.

Comment: This is not working sir in modern browsers, can you please check again

Comment: Warning: Please protect against LFI (Local File Inclusion) attack where a attacker might be able to read sensitive files from your server! This example might work for local server files (files stored on the PHP server), but on remote files the browser will still open the file instead of download.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this with video files (I want to offer a download, but the browser always tries to open it).

If you can't use a server-side language like dgig mentions, the only thing I've been able to do is put the file in a ZIP file and let the user download that.

Apple does this with Quicktime samples, and since they have more money and resources to throw at this than I do, I figured that was probably how I'd have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to write an `.htaccess` or edit the Apache config, you can also check [this proposed response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root?answertab=votes#tab-top) to force a download.