# .htaccess Force-Download for all but Images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, upload

I'd like to have my .htaccess set-up so uploads aren't executed and are forced to download if they're not images or videos. However I'm having some difficulty with this as I used to have it working but since changing hosts the htaccess no longer works, it instead creates a 500 error.

Previous .htaccess

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    ForceType none
    Header unset Content-Disposition
</FilesMatch>

Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

Comment: possible duplicate - hack through this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758866/257319

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing a download using <filesMatch> in htaccess at WWW root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root)