# Download a image file in php

Tags: php

I have a code , it works, i saved it with download.php , but i don't know, how to download the image file named simpletext.jpg present on the same root of the above mentioned file, I will be very thankful to you if you write the actual path, how to do that, the code is below....

```
$file_name = "a.txt";

// extracting the extension:
$ext = substr($file_name, strpos($file_name,'.')+1);

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);

if(strtolower($ext) == "txt")
{
    header('Content-type: text/plain'); // works for txt only
}
else
{
    header('Content-type: application/'.$ext); // works for all extensions 
except txt
}
readfile($decrypted_file_path);
```

Comment: if you're putting a link on a page to do it then put href as the path to the file and add a download attribute at the end of the <a> and it will download the file for you

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda....I need more help....if you write something...plz

Comment: What is the value of this: $decrypted_file_path

Comment: @Andreas Dear, What do you mean by value...?

Comment: The image file is present , it can be seen on the browser through browse, but when download it, the fire is getting error or / empty, why?

Comment: @ Dear Andreas, I need your suggestion....

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="localhost:8888/files/download.jpg" download>Click here to download the file</a>
```

substitute the href with your file path..

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/path/file_name.jpg" download="download_file_name">download</a>
```

download_file_name will replace file_name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the htaccess file to force downloads for image files. See this similar question:

Using Htaccess to force downloads [[Forcing a download using <filesMatch> in htaccess at WWW root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14388994/8031331])