# How to filter the listing of a directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, directory-listing

Is it possible to control how the web browser will display the listing of a directory on the (apache) server by using directives in .htaccess ? Typically I would like to display only the last 10 more recent files ? And also control the width of the column (presently long names are truncated) ?

Finally, files in the directory are text files with .log suffixe. How to force opening them in the web browser rather than downloading ?

Comment: You can change certain aspects of the layout, check the options mod_autoindex offers for configuration, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html But you can not limit the result to a specific number of files only - if you need that, then you need to find a custom solution (some script that reads the directory content, and displays it as you want.)

Comment: _“Finally, […]”_ - a bit more own research efforts would not go amiss here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess

Comment: This is not what the auto index feature of the http server is for. You should implement an own indexing logic instead which offers you complete freedom.

Comment: About the download issue, and the link to stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/…, it is quite the opposite I want to do. Presently my server (or the browser) forces to download files with extension log or txt. How to force then being opened in the browser ?